# The Ruby way to test if multiple variables are smaller than a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for the Ruby way to check if two variables (or more) are greater than a value.

Right now I have it the 'default' way:

```
if score1 < WINNING_SCORE && score2 < WINNING_SCORE
```

I'm curious about how to achieve this in DRY.

Comment: BTW, you are checking if they are `lesser`, not `greater`

Comment: Dunno, but in Lisp, operators can take arbitrarily many values: `(> 3 0 2 1 4)` is interpreted as "Is 3 greater than each of the other operands?". Same for summing: `(+ 3 2 1)`, AND/ORing, etc.

Comment: @vemv: Not sure about Lisp, but at least in Scheme `(> 3 5 4)` is false. It is not "is 3 greater than each of the other operands", it is "are the operands in ascending order".

Comment: @Amadan Great to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're in an array of something or if you put them in one you can do it like this:

```
[score1, score2].all? { |score| score < WINNING_SCORE }
```

Read up on `all?` [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F)

Comment: Both this answer and @Nerve's work (@Nerve's requires a tweak since it is looking at the reverse of the && statement, i.e. an OR statement, and that requires the tiniest bit of additional brainpower...)

Comment: I agree, didn't now about either of these until I needed them myself yesterday.  Pretty cool stuff

Answer (score 3):

If any of the score is greater than WINNING_SCORE, then the condition becomes false. Using `any` would be a bit more efficient.

```
[score1, score2].any?{|score| score > WINNING_SCORE}
```

Comment: Almost. The reverse of "greater" is not "smaller", but "smaller or equal".